# System of non-linear equations (ISNMO, 1991)

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations

Let $x,y,z$ be real numbers. Solve the following system of equations: $$\begin{cases}
\frac{3(x^2+1)}x=\frac{4(y^2+1)}y=\frac{5(z^2+1)}z;   \\
xy+xz+yz=1.
\end{cases}$$

I tried to solve this system using the following method:

Since $$\frac{3(x^2+1)}x=\frac{4(y^2+1)}y; \Rightarrow 3y(x^2+1)=4x(y^2+1).$$ Now, from the second row, we have $$3y(x^2+xy+xz+yz)=4x(y^2+xy+xz+yz); \Rightarrow (x+y)(xy+4xz-3yz)=0.$$
Thus, $$x=-y; z=\frac {xy}{3y-4x}.$$
But if we replace $y$ with $-x$, we obtain a complex solution. The same happens when we replace $z$ with $\frac {xy}{3y-4x}$ in the second row because it takes us back to the first expression $x=-y$.
Finally, in case we try to deal with $$\frac{3(x^2+1)}x=\frac{5(z^2+1)}z, z=\frac {xy}{3y-4x},$$
then it complicates the problem with huge expressions.

Wolfram Alpha shows that the real solutions are $(x;y;z)=(\frac 13;\frac 12;1)\cup(-\frac 13;-\frac 12;-1)$, but I do not know how to get to them. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "The same happens when we replace $z$ with $\frac {xy}{3y-4x}$ in the second row because it takes us back to the first expression $x=-y$." Could you elaborate on how do you get $x = -y$?

Comment: I would go about like this: You started with $3(x^2+1)/x=4(y^2+1)/y$. You already got $(x+y)(xy+4xz-3yz)=0$ and you saw that $x+y=0$ does not lead to any solution. So it must be that $xy+4xz-3yz=0$ (linear equation in $xy,yz,xz$). If you start with $4(y^2+1)/y=5(z^2+1)/z$ you will get another linear equation in $xy,yz,xz$. These two equations together with $xy+yz+xz=1$ gives you a system of three linear equations with three unknowns ($xy,yz,xz$), etc...

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's ISNMO?

Comment: Israeli National Mathematical Olympiad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on OP's work and my comments:

From the first double equality it is obvious that $x,y,z\ne 0$, and $x, y$ and $z$ have the same sign (since the numerators are positive). So one also has $x+y,y+z$, and $z+x\ne 0$

Then as in OP's idea, using the given:

$$xy+yz+xz=1 \tag{1}$$

One gets:

$$x^2+1=x^2+xy+yz+xz=x(x+y)+z(x+y)=(x+y)(x+z)$$

So the first double equality can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{3(x+y)(x+z)}{x}=\frac{4(y+x)(y+z)}{y}=\frac{5(z+x)(z+y)}{z}$$

From the first and middle side of the double equality above, as $x+y\ne 0$ one gets:

$$\frac{3(x+z)}{x}=\frac{4(y+z)}{y}\text{ which can be rewritten as }\frac{3z}{x}=\frac{y+4z}{y}$$

Which gives

$$xy-3yz+4xz=0\tag{2}$$

Similarly, from the middle and right side of the double inequality one gets:

$$5xy+yz-4xz=0\tag{3}$$

From $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ by denoting $u=xy, v=yz, w=zx$, one gets the linear system:

$$\left\{
\begin{alignat}{4}
u&+&v&+&w&=1\\
u&-&3v&+&4w&=0\\
5u&+&v&-&4w&=0
\end{alignat}
\right.$$

By solving with one's favorite method, one gets $u=\frac{1}{6}, v=\frac{1}{2}, w=\frac{1}{3}$

Furthermore $(xyz)^2=uvw=\frac{1}{36}$, so $xyz=\pm\frac{1}{6}$

So $x=\frac{xyz}{v}=\pm\frac{1}{3}, y=\frac{xyz}{w}=\pm\frac{1}{2}, z=\frac{xyz}{u}=\pm 1$

As $x,y$ and $z$ have the same sign, one gets the solutions $(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},1\right)$ and $\left(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-1\right)$

Answer (score 6):

(*Not a completely rigorous proof, but too long for a comment.*)

Let $\,x=\tan(a)\,$ and similar, then $\,\frac{x^2+1}{x}=\frac{2}{\sin(2a)}\,$, so the equations can be written as:

$$
\frac{3}{\sin(2a)}=\frac{4}{\sin(2b)}=\frac{5}{\sin(2c)} \tag{*}
$$

Also, $\,xy+yz+zx=1 \implies a+b+c=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\,$, by proving a converse of [if $ a + b + c = 90^{\circ}$, prove $ \tan(a) \cdot \tan(b) + \tan(b) \cdot \tan(c) + \tan(c) \cdot \tan(a) = 1 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342989/if-a-b-c-90-circ-prove-tana-cdot-tanb-tanb-cdot-tan), and therefore $\,2a+2b+2c=(2k+1)\pi\,$.

For positive $\,x,y,z\,$ the relation $\,(*)\,$ can be thought of as the law of sines in a right $3-4-5$ triangle with angles $\,2a,2b,2c = \frac{\pi}{2}\,$. It follows that the following are solutions:

- $\sin(2a)=\frac{3}{5} \implies \frac{x^2+1}{x} = 2 \cdot \frac{5}{3} \implies x = \frac{1}{3}$
- $\sin(2b)=\frac{4}{5} \implies \frac{y^2+1}{y} = 2 \cdot \frac{5}{4} \implies y = \frac{1}{2}$
- $\sin(2c)=1 \implies \frac{z^2+1}{z} = 2 \cdot 1 \implies z = 1$

This gives the positive solution $\,\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}, 1\right)\,$, and
the given relations require $\,x,y,z\,$ to all have the same sign, so there is one symmetric solution in negative numbers $\,\left(-\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{2}, -1\right)\,$.

Comment: An exciting solution! I would have not ever thought about using trigonometric substitutions. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MaxMen One clue might be the pythagorean 3-4-5 triple, which this line of proof makes good use of. As posted, there are two blanks left to fill-in, neither too difficult: (a) show that positive solutions can choose $k=0$ in $2a+2b+2c=(2k+1)\pi$ so that $2a,2b,2c$ are the angles of a triangle, and (b) the uniqueness of the positive solution, which is easier than [Prove the converse of the Law of Sines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412394/prove-the-converse-of-the-law-of-sines) given the triangle here is a right one.

Comment: @dxiv It looks like you nailed how the author created the system to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-Equalizing to $t$ each of the expressions in first line we have
$$3(x^2+1)=tx\\4(y^2+1)=ty\\5(z^2+1)=tz$$ we deduce
$$x=\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-36}}{6}\\y=\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-64}}{8}\\z=\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-100}}{10}$$Now taking into account the second line of the proposed system we have the solution given by Wolfram:
$$\left(\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-36}}{6}\right)\left(\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-64}}{8}\right)+\left(\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-36}}{6}+\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-64}}{8}\right)\left(\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-100}}{10}\right)=1$$ but it is not necessary if we before that $t=10$ is a good value.